# How do you find all first letter capitalized words in a string? Like a name ("My Name and another His Name")?

Tags: swift, regex, string, algorithm, character

GOAL: I want to have a regex that searches a string for all capitalized first letters of words/names in a string. Then replace those capitalized words with "Whatever", if the word is 4 or more characters long. Then replace words 4 or more letters that are lowercased with "whatever".

String Input:

```
let myString = "This is a regular string.  How does this Work?  Does any Name know How?"
```

Desired String Output:

```
let myString = "Whatever is a whatever whatever. How whatever this Whatever? Whatever any Whatever whatever whatever How?"
```

What I've tried:

```
let myString = "This is a regular string.  How does this Work?  Does any Name know How?"

let x = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{Lu}{4,}\\b",
                                                    with: "Whatever",
                                                    options: .regularExpression)
let finalX = x.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{L}{4,}\\b",
                                    with: "whatever",
                                    options: .regularExpression)
print(finalX)
```

Problem:

The first check is for capitalized letters, the second is for lowercased letters, but it still returns all lowercased.

Would anyone know how to go about this with what I have?

Comment: Try  `of: #"\b\p{Lu}\p{L}{3,}"#`

Comment: Tried that out and it still fails, found that the contains method search (myString.contains(".*[A-Z]+.*")) fails.. not sure if that's a Swift bug or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you want is the following:

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]{3,}\b
```

That will only work with the basic letters A-Z and a-z. If you want to fully support any alphabet then you would need something like this:

```
\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}{3,}\b
```

The \b means "word boundary". The \p{Lu} means "uppercase letters". The \p{Ll} means "lowercase letters".

You only want to use this in the call to `replacingOccurrences`. There's little reason to do the initial check using `contains`. That will be looking for the literal text you pass in and of course the regular expression you are using won't be found as literal text in the string.

```
let myString = "This is a regular string.  How does this Work?  Does any Name know How?"
let x = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}{3,}\\b",
                                                    with: "Whatever",
                                                    options: .regularExpression)
print(x)
```

Output:

> Whatever is a regular string.  How does this Whatever?  Whatever any Whatever know How?

To do both you also need `"\\b\\p{Ll}{4,}\\b"`.

The following changes both sets.

```
let myString = "This is a regular string.  How does this Work?  Does any Name know How?"
let x = myString
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{Ll}{4,}\\b",
                                                    with: "whatever",
                                                    options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}{3,}\\b",
                                                    with: "Whatever",
                                                    options: .regularExpression)
print(x)
```

Output:

> Whatever is a whatever whatever.  How whatever whatever Whatever?  Whatever any Whatever whatever How?

Comment: @HangerRash works great!  Excellent solution with explanation, thank you so much!

Do you know how to combine this regex to include all 4 letter words or more that are lowercased in the string with "whatever"?

Output:  "Whatever is a whatever whatever. How whatever this Whatever? Whatever any Whatever whatever whatever How?"

Comment: It's nearly the same. Just remove the uppercase check and modify the lowercase check to 4 or more: `"\\b\\p{L}{4,}\\b"`.

Comment: @HangerRash that outputs: Whatever is a Whatever Whatever.  How Whatever Whatever Whatever?  Whatever any Whatever Whatever How?

Is there something else to replace to get the lowercased 4 letter words to lowercased that are already lowercased?

Desired Output: "Whatever is a whatever whatever. How whatever this Whatever? Whatever any Whatever whatever whatever How?"

Comment: Tried this to combine searches, but the last search overrides the capitalization.
let myString = "This is a regular string.  How does this Work?  Does any Name know How?"
let x = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{Lu}\\b",
                                                    with: "Whatever",
                                                    options: .regularExpression)
let finalX = x.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b\\p{L}{4,}\\b",
                                           with: "whatever",
                                           options: .regularExpression)
print(finalX)

Comment: Updated the answer. I had a mistake. you need `\\p{Ll}` for lowercase. `\\p{L}` is any letter.

Comment: @HangerRash wow!  I had no clue we could chain methods like your answer, that's genius, you're a Swift legend (I mean it).  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Where did you learn regex like this so well??  
I've searched so many Swift Regex tutorials and such and none out there teach how to do real regex searches like this.

Comment: My first experience with regex was in the mid '80s. I've had time to learn :)